# Should I return my monitor for this backlight problem?

Tags: monitors, displays

I recently bought an LG 27UP850 monitor, it has IPS display with 400 nits of brightness. In very dark scenes, I notice that on top left of the display the backlight is brighter than other places, is this a problem or am I being too picky?
I can return the monitor if this is an issue.

[image: Backlight problem in LG monitor on top left of the display]

Comment: This is pretty common for IPS displays, and the manufacturer or store might not even consider this to be a defect. If there's a cost to returning it then you're paying to "roll the dice" and get another unit that is maybe worse or better. I wouldn't return it unless it bothers you, and if it does bother you then you might not want another IPS monitor at all.

Comment: Generally speaking, this is known as "backlight uniformity"; typically older, edge-lit displays suffer the most, but the 27UP850 shouldn't suffer too badly. It's hard to tell with your image, but subjectively that does look pretty bad; it's possible this unit is a lemon, but no guarantees. If backlight uniformity is a big deal to you, you might want to take a look at either a display with good reviews, or consider either an LCD with full-array local dimming or a OLED display.

Comment: @JMY1000
Of course, an OLED display or similar technologies with local dimming would be ideal, the problem is the price. I bought this 4k monitor with USB-C for 299 euros, the OLEDs start at two to three times this price and they might not even come with a USB-C and they are usually labeled as gaming monitors, so a lot of extra stuff and bold designs which is not desired and just increases the price.

Comment: Yeah totally makes sense, just wanted to bring up alternatives in case you weren’t aware of them (though it seems like you are.) At €300 I’d probably be inclined to keep it?